# get characters up to first occurrence of 'x' from reverse

Tags: javascript, regex

i want to split the string up to first occurrence of 'dot' from right to left match.

```js
//if i have the input string as follows

    var string = "hi.how.you" ;
//i need the output as following

  output="you";
```

Comment: Split by `.` and get the last element. Why use regex?

Answer (score 2):

You can `split` by DOT and use `pop()` to get the last element of the resulting array:

```
var string = "hi.how.you" ;
var last = string.split('.').pop()
//=> you
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and the most efficient way is to find the last `.` with [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) and [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring):

```js
var s = "hi.how.you";
s = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
// It will return the part after the last `.`
console.log(s);
// It will return the input string if `.` is missing
console.log("hihowyou".substring("hihowyou".lastIndexOf(".") + 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either split and pop

```
"hi.how.you".split(".").pop()
```

or you can match it with a bunch of different reg exp:

```
"hi.how.you".match(/\.([^\.]+)$/)[1]
```